# Best book for self-study on the foundations of probability

Tags: probability, book-recommendation

After some selection, I have three "candidates" books to purchase in order to study by myself the foundations of the theory of probability, at a level that I can define as "high undergraduate"/"low graduate". These are my candidates:

1) Probability. A.N.Shiryaev. GTM Springer-Verlag.

2) Probability and Stochastics. Erhan Çinlar. GTM Springer-Verlag.

3) Probability Theory. A. Borovkov. UT Springer-Verlag.

I have very good references from all of them.
Which one do you recommend me ?

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Haven't used any of those. One feature of any good book for self study is a good amount of problems *with solutions* in the book. It's very easy to misunderstand or think you know something without working some problems. I'd suggest a couple others to at least take a look at: The Theory of Probability by Santosh Venkatesh (no solutions, but I learned "mature" probability from this book and the writing is great). Probability and Measure Theory by Ash (has detailed solutions in the back), Probability and Measure by Billingsley.

Comment: Thank you Eupraxis. Although these are my candidates, I appreciate other recommendations. I'll take a look at them.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "foundations" - if you are looking for a book which starts by introducting measure spaces, random variables, integration etc., i heard highly of Williams' "probability with martingales" (although I didn't read it myself, I studies from Durrett's book which I didn't really like)

Comment: Nobody has references of my three candidates books ?

Comment: I'm not a mathematician, but based on my experience, I found #1 is probably quite hard, as the proof is very limited. However, the book is masterpiece at is own, it is highly cited in research field. I've read David Williams, "Probability with martingale" and I think I like the way he wrote the book, and the book is really organized, and gives quite complete proofs. After reading this book, you can easily jump to "Diffusions, Markov Processes, and Martingales", vol 1 by L. C. G. Rogers, David Williams.

Comment: I believe suggestions really depend on how much measure theory one knows.

Answer (score 7):

I would reccomend just using lecture notes available online. That way you have no risk from purchasing a book.

Some good ones:
http://www.math.nyu.edu/faculty/varadhan/limittheorems.html

http://www-stat.stanford.edu/~adembo/stat-310a/lnotes.pdf

https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-175-theory-of-probability-spring-2014/lecture-slides

Answer (score 3):

I have used the first two, but do not know the third one.

Shyriaev's book is more computational and shows the proofs for all the theorems and propositions, to all small details. Cinlar is more abstract and skips many intermediate steps, but goes into more depth in other directions. Both are good books, but I think Shiryaev is better for self-study.

However, I would look for a book with solutions to the problems if you are planning to do it all by yourself.

Good luck!